# Why does Ubuntu take so long to boot?

Tags: 12.04, boot, bootchart

I'm having really slow boot times. I don't know what's going on with my computer, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.2 and my boot time is really slow. How can I speed it up?

This is the boot chart.
[BootChart](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9JAdrUOxzfKRVFMV1E0VEw3blE/edit?usp=sharing)

My computer specs:

```
Lenovo IdeaPad U310 
Intel core i5-3317U - 1.7 GHz (2.6 GHz max freq)
500GB HDD - 5400RPM 
4GB RAM 
Intel® HD 4000 (integrated)
```

Comment: Add your /var/log/syslog

Comment: @psusi https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9JAdrUOxzfKa3A5YUxfWk8zRFU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Something seems to be wrong with your sata controller and it doesn't want to reset properly.  Try adding libata.force=nohrst to your kernel command line in /etc/default/grub, and run `sudo update-grub` to make it take effect on the next boot.

Comment: Should I Leave the kernel option set for future reboots or leave it there indefinitely?

Comment: Are you referring these lines?

`[    6.259091] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   10.901535] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   16.255129] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   20.897624] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   26.259158] ata1: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   55.903724] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   55.903729] ata1: limiting SATA link speed to 3.0 Gbps
[   60.929712] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[   60.929717] ata1: reset failed, giving up`

Comment: @VictorAlejandroMartinez, yes.  If it works, then yea, leave it there.